# Custom post type with taxonomy children

Tags: php, wordpress, parent-child, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

Through landing we are showing categories. Clicking on any category show child sub categories. But this shows child of child as well. following is our code to retrieve sub categories.

```
$terms = get_terms( 'msproduct' );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<li>' . $term->name . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

please advice. My category structure is following

```
Commercial Ovan
- 900 Series
-- Product 1
-- Product 2
- 700 Series
-- Product 1
- 600 Series
-- Product 1
-- Product 2
-- Product 3
-- Product 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use this. I'm not sure what your structure is, but assuming the page you're on `is_tax()` then checking against that conditional may work.

```
$taxonomy = "msproduct";
$args = (is_tax()) ? array() : array('parent' => 0); // don't show children if you're on a taxonomy page
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );

if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<li>' . $term->name . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Reference:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Commercial Ovan is the main category it contain direct product and sub categories. If it comes to category it can have one product or multiple products. index.php, taxonomy-msproduct.php, single-msproduct.php are the pages. If its a direct product clicking on it will take me to single page with all the details. but what if it contain more then one product then a loop of products will be shown. This is all about